# Why does ERT say my test is aborted?

Tags: unit-testing, emacs, elisp, ert

I'm trying out writing some elisp for the first time. I'd like to be able to run unit tests on it.

I have a buffer with the following in it:

```
(ert-deftest addition-test ()
  (should (= (+ 1 2) 4)))
```

And I ran `M-x eval-buffer` to install the `ert-deftest` definition into my emacs. When I run `M-x ert RET t RET`, I see:

```
Selector: t
Passed: 0
Failed: 0
Total:  0/1

Started at:   2015-11-16 00:27:46-0800
Aborted.
Aborted at:   2015-11-16 00:27:46-0800

A

A addition-test
    aborted
```

And I see the message "Test failed: ...." in the minibuffer at the bottom of the screen. Why is the failure reported there rather in the ERT buffer?

EDIT:

It appears that the "aborted" message occurs after a failing test is hit, then any remaining tests aren't run. Example:

```
(ert-deftest test1 ()
  (should 1))

(ert-deftest test2 ()
  (should nil))

(ert-deftest test3 ()
  (should 1))
```

`M-x eval-buffer RET M-x ert RET` opens up a buffer named `*ert*` that says:

```
Selector: t
Passed: 1
Failed: 0
Total:  1/3

Started at:   2015-11-16 02:06:57-0800
Aborted.
Aborted at:   2015-11-16 02:06:57-0800

.A-

A test2
    aborted
```

And in `*Messages*` I see:

```
Aborted: Ran 3 tests, 1 results were as expected
ert-fail: Test failed: ((should nil) :form nil :value nil)
```

If I go in the `*ert*` and press `d` over `test2`, I get the following in `*Messages*`:

```
Running test test2...ABORTED
ert-fail: Test failed: ((should nil) :form nil :value nil)
```

I can convince it to run `test3` if I hit enter on the `-` in `.A-`, expand `test3`, then hit `d` on it. That looks like:

```
Selector: t
Passed: 2
Failed: 0
Total:  2/3

Started at:   2015-11-16 02:08:40-0800
Aborted.
Aborted at:   2015-11-16 02:08:40-0800

.A.

A test2
    aborted

. test3
    passed
```

In terms of getting a backtrace, hitting `b` over `test2` gives me:

```
ert-results-pop-to-backtrace-for-test-at-point: cl-etypecase failed: [cl-struct-ert-test-aborted-with-non-local-exit  (((should nil) :form nil :value nil))], (ert-test-passed ert-test-result-with-condition)
```

I don't understand the output of the backtrace at all. This behavior doesn't seem to match what the ERT documentation says so I'm really puzzled. What's going on here?

Comment: It runs fine on Emacs 24.5. Maybe it's a variant of http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21701 ? Try to re-run the test using the "d" key, hopefully you will see a backtrace of the error.

Comment: Also, `ert` doesn't seem to be aware of `=`, try using `equal` instead.

Comment: @Lindydancer It produces a better error message in the message line below, but still gives me `aborted`. I've played around more and it looks like it runs tests in alphabetical order until it hits one that fails, then prints out the failure message in the bottom minibuffer, then refuses to run the rest. I'll edit with an example --- is ert just broken? Running with `d` produces the same result.

Comment: @Lindydancer I've added more details, and found some sort of backtrace. I'm not sure if it's what you were looking for.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that I'm running Emacs 24.3.1.

Comment: I just ran this in Emacs 24.3.1 on Windows, and it seems to run fine. Does it happen when you run `emacs -Q`? If it works, there is probably something in your init file that interferes with ert.

Comment: @Lindydancer Yep, it works fine in a clean emacs. Hm. Any idea how I'd go about finding what the problem package is? Also, if you'd like to move this in to an answer I'd be happy to accept. EDIT: Even restarting my current emacs session (without -Q) fixed it. I guess I pulled in something weird along the way. I think at one point I tried to `(require 'cl)` because I wasn't clear if the `cl-*` functions would come without it, I guess that might have broken something deep down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted works in a clean Emacs started with `emacs -Q`. Most likely, it is caused by some library that has been loaded somehow.